# classes not exported when using string literal `space-x-${props.bgSize}`

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite, string-literals

I'm working on an app using Vite & Vuejs3 where I'm setting up a conditional class.
In there I've got a tailwind (unocss) class which also is conditionally created with a variable, like so...

```
:class="[dirHor ? `flex-row bottom-0 left-50% -translate-x-50% mb-6 space-x-${props.bgSize}` : `flex-col right-0 top-50% -translate-y-50% mr-6 space-y-${props.bgSize}`]"
```

It's the `space-x-${props.bgSize}` here for example which isn't exported. When you hardcode the variable into the class like `space-x-8` it does work.

Seems here that the string literals are correctly implemented, and available in the app (html) but the classes aren't available for this, as they weren't decided on, when exporting?
For example (just as a test I added the numbers 24 into the string literals):

```
 <div
    class="absolute rounded-full"
    :class="[`w-${24} h-${24} -translate-x-${(24 / 2) - 1} -translate-y-${(24) / 2}`]"
  />
```

[Screenshot: DevTools html screenshot from this div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDTfV.png)

But it seems the classes for `w-24` and `h-24` are not exported

I would like to be able to control these classes with parameters so I can still determine the style based on the UI configuration.
Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Thanks
Pieter

Answer (score 0):

TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

```
`space-x-${props.bgSize}`
```

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Instead, you must include the full name of the class in your source code. You can return the full value by a function something like this

```
function  myFunc(val) {
return "space-x-"+val ;
}
```

where `val` is your size value you are passing like 24 here.

Then you can use them in DOM like this

```
 <div
    class="absolute rounded-full"
    :class=`${myFunc(props.bgSize)}`
  />
```

By doing it this way, the entire string for every class is in your source code, so TailwindCSS will know to generate the applicable CSS.

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks for your reply.
I've been trying to implement this into my project however I'm running into the same issue.

    const msize = 8
    const classFunc = (v: string | number) => {
      return `space-x-${v}`
    }
    :class="[dirHor ? `flex-row bottom-0 left-50% -translate-x-50% mb-6 ${classFunc(msize)}` : `flex-col right-0 top-50% -translate-y-50% mr-6`]"

Not sure if I'm misinterpretation anything you suggested.

Also if I add in a space-x-8, remove it and use an msize=8 this works, however other values don't. They don't seem to be generated using the function?

Comment: Although I dont know `VueJS` but the function should return a string value so that tailwind can undestand it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I expect the issue to be with vite(?) which handles all the conversions and assets as well. Not sure.

If anyone has experience with this I'd love to know if this is possible, and how this could be done.

For now I've reverted back to static classes to make sure everything works properly.